# map through list stored in state - react

Tags: reactjs, state, map-function

I'm trying to map through a list that is stored in the state and pass each item in the list as a prop to another component. Here is what it looks like. The video component is supposed to receive each item from the playlist, title, and description lists then render each video, appropriate title and description until the playlist is over. It seems like the code is rendering the video component but nothing actually shows up.

This is the component that fetches the data and calls the video component.

```
export class YoutubeFetch extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      playlist: [],
      title: [],
      description: [],
      thumbnails: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // console.log('responseJson', responseJson)
        const playlist = responseJson.items.map(obj => "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + obj.snippet.resourceId.videoId);
        this.setState({ playlist });
        const description = responseJson.items.map(obj => obj.snippet.description);
        this.setState({ description });
        const thumbnails = responseJson.items.map(obj => obj.snippet.thumbnails.default.url);
        this.setState({ thumbnails });
        const title = responseJson.items.map(obj => obj.snippet.title);
        this.setState({ title });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          {this.state.playlist.map((index) =>
            <Video
              key={index}
              video={this.state.playlist[index]}
              title={this.state.title[index]}
              description={this.state.description[index]}
            />
          )}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the video component. In the video component, I added a test h1 to see whats happening. The test h1 renders with gaps in between where it seems like the video and etc are supposed to render.

```
function Video(props) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <ReactPlayer
          controls
          url={props.video}
          // height="75%"
          playing={false}
          width="100%"
        />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        <p>{props.description}</p>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Video
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, do not use class components now.

the issue is here

```
video={this.state.playlist[index]}
```

this index is not number based value it is the value present in the array of `playlist`

to access the number use the second parameter in the map

```
 {this.state.playlist.map((value,index) =>
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem.. Missed the second parameter.
Curious why I shouldn't use class components? Is it outdated?

Comment: yes, it is outdated. if you look at new react docs all examples are based on functional components.
https://beta.reactjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this this way too . create a render function  that stores all your  components in one array and then return it

```
const renderMyList = () =>{
mylist = [];
for(let i = 0; i<this.state.playlist.length;i++){
mylist.append(<Video
              key={i}
              video={this.state.playlist[i]}
              title={this.state.title[i]}
              description={this.state.description[i]}
            />) 
}
return mylist;
}
```

and finally, call this render function

```
render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          {renderMyList()}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: good approach , clean code